# What's difference between `2 == {}` and `{} == 2`

Tags: javascript, equality

When I type `2 == {}` on Chrome developer tools, it will return `false`, but when I type `{} == 2`, I get a Error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==`. What's hell `==` have done?

Comment: `{}` is parsed as block. I guess.

Comment: because `{` and `}` have two purposes ... object declaration and code block

Comment: @Vic I don't know. maybe someone knows the syntax more? maybe a `language lawyer` tag is helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{` is syntactically ambiguous. It is used in expressions (object literal syntax, `{foo: 42, bar: "hello"}`) and in statements (block, `{ foo(); bar(); baz(); }`).

If a `{` occurs at the beginning of a statement, it is always parsed as the start of a block.

Thus

```
{} == 2
```

parses as

```
{
    // empty block
}
== 2  // syntax error
```

On the other hand, in `2 == {}`, the `{` appears in the middle of an expression and is treated as an object.

This is also how you can make `{} == 2` work: Just make sure the `{` is not the first token, which you can do by e.g. writing `({}) == 2` or `({} == 2)`.

Comment: why `{} == {}` pass?

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable! Aha, same question as @appleapple

Comment: @appleapple `{} == {}` still gives me `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '=='`.

Comment: ``{} == {}`` -> ``false``, ``{} == {};`` -> ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==``

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. The Chrome console is doing weird things with leading `{`.

Comment: {} == {}  is considered as comparison while {} == {}; is considered as assignment

Comment: I think it's more a Chrome console thing, shift this to another block and will fail again.. eg.. `{{}=={}}`,..  I assume it's maybe a dev helper, eg. doing `{}` is a quick way to view the Object prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You might wrap it in parentheses to distinguish from a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). Then you get an [epression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions).

```
({} === 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you write {} in javascript, it implies object. You can declare object in braces {}.
so {} == 2 or 2=={} is same.and in this case , both statment return false.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, an object is a value in memory which is referenced by an identifier.
Primitive values can be compared with other types but when you try to compare an undeclared object, it can't be compared as there is no identifier to it. If you first declare it :

```
var object ={};
object == 2;
```

This returns `false` because now there is an identifier to the object being referenced. When you don't declare it, it acts as a block.